# LINQ - OrderByDescending

Tags: c#, linq

Please note: As of 1:47 PM UTC, Aug 26 2016, I completely modified this question because originally it was very confusing. My fault for that. So please ignore all answers/comments before this time. Thanks

I have a list of items that get added to a SearchItems list by SearchType... SearchType  of ObjectAType, ObjectBType etc.. I want to OrderByDescending SearchTimes by items that have SearchType of ObjectAType or ObjectBType. For all other SearchType it needs to be order by ascending.

This is my query:

```
var orderdItems = SearchItems.OrderBy(i => i.ItemDisplay)
                             .OrderBy(i => i.CategoryDisplay))
```

This is the criteria I want to order by descending.

```
Where(x => x.SearchType == ObjectAType || x.SearchType == ObjectBType)
```

This is the structure of SearchItem

```
public class SearchItem
{
    public SearchItem() { }
    public Guid ItemId { get; set; }
    public string ItemDisplay { get; set; }
    public string CategoryDisplay { get; set; }
    public string SearchType { get; set; }
}
```

And this is how they get added to `SearchItems = List<SearchItems>();`

```
SearchItems.AddRange(items.Select(i => new SearchItem()
            {
                CategoryDisplay = "Object A",
                ItemDisplay = i.ObjectADisplay,
                ItemId = i.ObjectAId,
                SearchType = ObjectAType,
            }));

SearchItems.AddRange(items.Select(i => new SearchItem()
            {
                CategoryDisplay = "Object B",
                ItemDisplay = i.ObjectBDisplay,
                ItemId = i.ObjectBId,
                SearchType = ObjectBType,
            }));
```

and so on....'items' are `IEnumerable<ObjectA>, IEnumerable<ObjectB>` etc..

Comment: How are you going to sort 2 of 26 items in a single collection? That in itself does not make sense, its like saying I want letters C and F sorted in the list of alphabetic characters. What would you do with the rest? I am thinking though there is something that either you are not telling us or not explaining with enough details. For example: is this a list of items where each item then also has lists and you want 2 of those containers to be sorted? You need to provide the model structure for the types you want sorted with a bit more information.

Comment: Perhaps there's a way to write two queries and then combine the result before serializing?

Comment: Your explanation of the problem does not make technical sense. Do you just want 2 items to appear first in the list before the other 26? Thats very easy to do but you cant sort on part of a list, you sort everything either explicitly or implicitly (this will always happen) or nothing.

Comment: You say "...  and still return ALL 26 objects ...". Why should sorting not return all objects? Do you mean 2 object descending and all the others ascending?

Comment: I agree with @Igor. How about you filter 2 of 26 objs and sort them as you wish, then filter out the other 24 objs and put them together in an sorted list with the 2 desired/fitered/sorted objs first? It sounds to me you have to do two separate filtering/sorting and put it together in one unsorted list with the 2 sorted objs first...

Comment: Is this what you mean? `.OrderBy(x => (x.SearchType == Foo || x.SearchType == Bar) ? 0 : 1)` ? If its one of your 2 types then have it ordered as the first items and then do not care about sorting on any other criteria?

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes yes that exactly what i mean. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Forgot to mention the Objects themselves are a list. So they have items that need to be order by descending but the other object not.

Comment: That's very confusing! Of what type exactly are the objects? Because if they are some `List<T>`, then they cannot have an `ItemDisplay` and a `CategoryDisplay` property. (`T` of course can.)

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes indeed. I am voting to close the question on the account of it being very ambiguous.

Comment: Its actually List<SearchItem> and each SearchItem has those two properties.

Comment: If you want to sort the object in the list, why are you saying that the objects themselves are lists? It makes no sense.

Comment: Is the serialization relevant? It just seems to add noise to the question.

Comment: Sorry guys, I rephrased the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var desc = this.SearchItems
               .Where(x => x.SearchType == Foo || x.SearchType == Bar)
               .OrderByDescending(i => i.ItemDisplay)
               .ThenByDescending(i => i.CategoryDisplay);
var asc = this.SearchItems
              .Where(x => x.SearchType != Foo && x.SearchType != Bar)
              .OrderBy(i => i.ItemDisplay)
              .ThenBy(i => i.CategoryDisplay);
var result = desc.Concat(asc);
```

Of course you can do it as one query as well.

I assume that you want the 2 descending objects first. If that's not the case then turn the last statement around.

```
var result = asc.Concat(desc);
```

If you want to sort the list itself, then do this

```
this.SearchItems = desc.Concat(asc).ToList();
```

Comment: I did something like this before but I will try it since its slightly different tomorrow and let you know, thanks everyone!

Comment: Looks like even after modification to the original question, this technique worked for me! Thank you Oliver!

Answer (score 1):

The question is rather confusing, but if I've understood correctly you've got 26 objects and you want a serialized list of those objects such that Object A is first, then Object B, then all remaining objects ordered by Property C.

If so, that can be written by ordering by the object being Object A first.

```
SearchItemsJson = serializer.Serialize(
                    this.SearchItems
                        .OrderByDescending(i => i.SearchType == "Foo")
                        .ThenByDescending(i => i.SearchType == "Bar")
                        .ThenBy(i => i.ItemDisplay)
                        .ThenBy(i => i.CategoryDisplay))
```

Having said that, it sounds like you hardcoding some logic about the objects that probably belongs as a property of the object. What is special about these two objects that mean they need to be listed first. Might you have a third special object in future? Adding a flag such as "Featured" to the object may be a more flexible way of modelling the business problem you are trying to solve.

Answer (score 0):

```
SearchItems.OrderBy(x => (x.SearchType == Foo || x.SearchType == Bar) ? 0 : 1);
```

That will result with `SearchType` = `Foo` or `Bar` at the top of the list and everything else after it. You can get more specific if you want Foo before Bar with:

```
SearchItems.OrderBy(x => x.SearchType == Foo ? 0 : x.SearchType == Bar ? 1 : 2);
```

In your example I have no idea what `SearchType` is or `Foo` or `Bar` but I think you get the idea.

In this example the type that will be used for sorting is `int` and default sorting is Ascending (small to large). So the OrderBy expression above will return `0` for `Foo` placing it first, `1` for `Bar` placing it 2nd, and `2` for anything else placing those after Foo and Bar.

Comment: @User123 - I added a description at the end.

Comment: Okay i used approach 1 but now objects not A or B their items are neither ordered in ascending nor descending order. they're all just floating wherever.